# How to verify that $\chi_{\{x \in X; f(x) > t \}}$ is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

## Question

Let $(X, m, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ a nonnegative measurable simple function.

I want to show that $\chi_{ \{ x \in X; f(x) > t \} }\ (t > 0)$ is integrable at this time.

## What I know

Just show the following.
$$
\int_X |\chi_{ \{ x \in X; f(x) > t \} }| d\mu < \infty
$$

## What I really want to know

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \mu(\{x\in X; f(x) > t\}) d\mu = \int_0^\infty \int_X \chi_{ \{ x \in X; f(x) > t \} } dt d\mu \\
\overset{\textrm{Fubini}}{=} \int_X \int_0^\infty \chi_{ \{ x \in X; f(x) > t \} } d\mu dt = \int_X \int_0^{f(x)} dt d\mu = \int_X f d\mu.
\end{align}

I want to use Fubini's theorem, but it means I can't say integrability.

Comment: Tonelli's Theorem does not require integrability.

Comment: Not sure to understand the question. Let $f$ be the constant 1, defined over $X=\Bbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure. Then, for $t=0$ we have $\{x\in\Bbb{R}\mid f(x)>0\}=\Bbb{R}$, and $\chi_{\Bbb{R}}=f$, which doesn't seem to be integrable.